# Multiple controllers on the same view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

How can I call two or more controllers in the same view like this:

```
.when('/func', {
  controller: 'ListController' ,
  controller: 'AddController',
  templateUrl: 'views/funcionario/func.html'
})
```

or this:

```
.when('/card', {
    controller: ['ListController','AddController'],  
    templateUrl: 'views/cardapio.html'
})
```

Comment: You can't. A view is controlled by one and only one controller. It can use ng-controller inside its template so that some part of the template is handled by another controller though.

Comment: If you want to organize a view's logic into reusable parts then you'll want to use services or directives instead of multiple controllers

Answer (score 0):

You can't set two controllers in your route, but you could set one in your route and then use ng-controller to set another as part of your template.

For example:

```
.when('/card', { 
    controller: 'ListController',
    templateUrl:'views/cardapio.html'
}
```

Then in your template:

```
<div ng-controller="AddController">
//part of html that you can to use AddController for
</div>
```

Its not generally recommended best practice to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

`<div ng-view></div>
<div ng-controller="SecondController"></div>`

In the ng-view you would load your view/controller as defined in your $routeProvider and have the SecondController take care of the second div.